# Verb to be before pronoun in declarative sentences

Tags: grammar, verbs, word-order, subject-verb-inversion, be

I saw this sentence in a newspaper cartoon:

> Not only are you dysfunctional — you appear to be completely spineless as well.

Is the verb *are* in the right position?

Comment: Yes, this is an exception to the rules available only when a negative constituent (like _not only_) is moved to the front of the sentence. In this case, subject-auxiliary inversion is required after the negative. So ***You are** not only `X` but also (you are) `Y`* becomes _Not only **are you** `X` but also (you are) `Y`_. The repeated _(you are)_ in the second clause gets deleted by conjunction reduction.

Comment: If you are an English-language learner, you might like to take a look at our sister-site, [ell.se]. That’s because that one there is a Q&A site **especially made for *learners***, while this one here is instead a Q&A site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.**